# British TV series with robot dog and post-apocalypse

Tags: story-identification

I watched as a child, so not long ago, but because of my age, I must have watched the German dub, or there were subtitles, which may explain my confusion. Some memories are jumbled, so it is hard to recall, but there were aliens in the show, and a girl was crushed by some metal. The dog saved the main characters a lot, who were children. It was a children's show.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Was it a cartoon or live-action, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a [K-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-9_(TV_series)) children's series; it would have been broadcast around 2009-2010.

The title character is a robot dog, based on one seen in *Doctor Who* and *The Sarah Jane Adventures*. The owner of the the copyright on K-9 allowed the character to be used (sparingly) in those shows, but was not allowed to reference either show in this series.

As I've never seen it, I cannot say if it would have even seemed as if it was post-apocalyptic. It appears to have been set in London in the "near future"; however, there was an element of time travel to the show, which might have resulted in adventures with a post-apocalyptic backdrop.

It was a live action show, with CGI.

I should note that the Wikipedia page lists a number of countries where it was shown, and the channel it was on in each, but that Germany was not included in that list. Not sure if that's just missing information, or if that means it wasn't shown in Germany.

Here's a link to the first episode on YouTube (in English):

Comment: It could also be the Sarah Jane Adventures, another Doctor Who spin-off in which K-9 appears. I think there were a couple of episodes of it that showed potentially apocalyptic events.

Comment: @ConMan - Not impossible, but I wouldn't say he "saved the main characters a lot, who were children", in SJA.

Comment: True, I think your answer is much more likely. Just mentioning it in case.

Comment: No problems - always good to provide alternatives!

Comment: Thank you, this is it! I did not know it was a doctor who show.